# How to concatenate a result from only one column of a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm still fairly new to oracle SQL and have a basic understanding of it but I'm really stuck on a problem I'm doing. I'm trying to pull the first 10 results from a table called 'tickets'. I want to then return the ticket id and append the string 'v1' to the end of the ID and return my results by the ticket IDs. I'm not quite sure how to concatenate the string to only one of the columns while still pulling the rest of the columns and leaving them alone. As of now, what I've been thinking is somewhere along the lines of this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tickets
WHERE (SELECT ticket_ID || 'v1'
        FROM tickets
        WHERE rownum => 10)
ORDER BY ticket_ID
```

Now I'm sure this is pretty wrong but I'm pretty stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way to do it. Please see that When you use to put star later part of you query you must use the table name or alias with it else it will return an issue

> "missing expression"

```
SELECT t.ticket_ID || 'v1' , t.* 
FROM tickets t
WHERE rownum <= 10 ORDER BY t.ticket_ID;
```